# OnPreferenceChangeListener dont gets called

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listener

I want to change the value of an EditTextPreference when an item in another ListPreference is clicked. But the OnPreferenceChangeListener never gets called.

Heres my code:

```
public class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

  /*@Override
  public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
  }*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new UserPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("PREF_MEASURE_UNITS");
        if(listPreference.getValue()==null) {
            // to ensure we don't get a null value
            // set first value by default
            listPreference.setValueIndex(0);
        }
        //listPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue().toString());
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                //preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                EditTextPreference EditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("PREF_CAMERA_HEIGHT");
                if (newValue.equals(0))
                {

                    EditTextPreference.setText(String.format("%.1f",Float.valueOf(EditTextPreference.getText().replace(',','.'))*2.54f));
                }
                else if (newValue.equals(1))

                    EditTextPreference.setText(String.format("%.1f",Float.valueOf(EditTextPreference.getText().replace(',','.'))/2.54f));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the solution.

I had to place the code beneath

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new UserPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
```

in the class

```
public  class UserPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment{
```

Now its working